# Certain character doesn't show in Terminal app (BASH specifically)

Tags: bash, terminal

Am using MacOS 10.12.3, have a problem where in Terminal app (ONLY), I cannot key the lower "r" character...it just blinks. All other keyboard characters are fine.

If I use another account, no problem. If I use zsh, no problem. I installed 4.4.12 of BASH from Homebrew and it has the same problem as 3.3.2 (blinks, the 'r' not accepted.

I checked LANG and locale is all UTF-8 as I expected. Anybody know what gives or how  to fix? Is there a login file I need to look at, and what am I looking for?

TIA Chris

UPDATE: bind -p shows 'r' is NOT self-inserting (all others ARE). How do I fix this, remember I cannot do a bash -r to fix it! Is there a file I can modify?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferent) OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: As well as your bash startup files, check the [readline initialization file](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9), usually `.inputrc` in your home directory.